A bounded analytic function in a domain only have removable singularity or not
Let $\delta$, be an open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$, Let $E= \{ z_1 ,z_2,z_3, \dots , z_n\}$. Suppose $f:\delta\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a function such that $f$ restricted to $\delta\setminus E$ analytic. then $f$ is analytic in $\delta$ if

$f$ is continuous in $\delta$
$f$ is bounded in $\delta$
The laurent expansion  of $f$ with respect to $z_i$ reduces to a taylor series for each $i$.

My attempt
If $f$ is analytic at each $z_i$ the each of them should be a removable singularity, condition for the removable singularity is
$\lim_{z\to z_i} (z-z_i) f(z)=0$. This implies that 1 and 2 is correct,3 is also correct since taylor expansion is valid inside the circle with centre $z_i$. It turns out that 1 and 3 is correct 2 is false. What is wrong with my assumption here

The boundedness of $f$ tells you that there exists an analytic extension to the entire domain. However, this extension needs not to coincide with $f$. For example pick $\delta=B(0,1)$ the open ball of radius $1$ around the origin and
$$ f(z)=\begin{cases} 1,& z\in B(0,1)\setminus \{0\}, \\ 0,& z=0. \end{cases} $$
This function is bounded, but not even continuous and hence not analytic. However, $f\vert_{B(0,1)\setminus \{0\}}$  admits an analytic extension to $B(0,1)$, namely the constant $1$ function.
In a nutshell, the problem is that just because $f\vert_{\delta\setminus E}$ has only removable singularities, does not imply that the analytic extension coincides with $f$ (and therefore we cannot conclude that $f$ is analytic, only that we could make it analytic if we would change the values of $f$ at points in $E$ correctly).
